# How to check if value is true?

Tags: swift, struct

I have a struct:

```
public struct TextFormat: Equatable {

  var bold: Bool
  var italic: Bool
  var underline: Bool
  var strikethrough: Bool

  public init() {
    self.bold = false
    self.italic = false
    self.underline = false
    self.strikethrough = false
  }
}

var format: TextFormat = TextFormat()
```

How do I check if the value of format.bold == true or format.italic == true, basically I want to check which value in the struct is true and print only the value that's true?

Comment: If you want to *print only the value that's true* you should use an enum. What's going to happen if bold **and** italic are true?

Comment: @vadian ya if bold and italic are true I want to print both the values.

Comment: What are you stuck with, I fail to see what is difficult about this? And what exactly do you want to print?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm not sure how do I get the values that's true.eg: if format.bold == true && format.italic == true i need to print "format:{bold, italic}". So how do i check in struct which values are true? I know that in array.contains(.true) works

Comment: You check each individual property, `if format.bold { … }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the init method is not needed

To print the `true` values a possible solution is to add a computed property

```
public struct TextFormat: Equatable {
    var bold = false
    var italic = false
    var underline = false
    var strikethrough = false
    
    var status : String {
        var result = [String]()
        if bold { result.append("bold") }
        if italic { result.append("italic") }
        if underline { result.append("underline") }
        if strikethrough { result.append("strikethrough") }
        return result.joined(separator: ", ")
    }
}
```

Certainly there are other ways.

Answer (score 1):

You are going the wrong way what you need here is an enumeration:

```
enum TextFormat: String, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {
    case bold, italic, underline, strikethrough
    var description: String { rawValue }
}
```

---

Now you can create a set:

```
let formats: Set<TextFormat> = [.bold, .italic]

print("formats:", formats)
print("all formats:", TextFormat.allCases)
print("is bold:", formats.contains(.bold))
```

---

This will print:

> formats: [italic, bold]
> all formats: [bold, italic, underline, strikethrough]
> is bold: true